# Cypress : Setting a variable from the result of a task

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, task, cypress

I need to retrieve an url from an email that was sent during the begining of a cypress scenario.

Waiting for the email and retrieving the url inside it is an asynchronous task, so I created a cypress plugin called "readMail" : it will take the email address as input, wait for the gmail api to actually have an email whose recipient is this address, then read the mail and return a promise resolving an url contained in the body of the email. This process works fine, because logs from the plugin do correctly show the extracted url.

My issue is to make this `extractedUrl` available for later use as a param e.g. `cy.visit(extractedUrl)` : outside the body of `task(...).then(...)`, the variable is still not set.

Here is the code :

```js
it('should generate correct email', () => {
    const recipientEmail: string = 'some@email.com';
    const extractedUrl:string = '';

    // ....scenario generating a email to 'some@email.com'.....

    cy.task('readMail', recipientEmail) // plugin logs "https://some.url.com" after a few seconds
    .then((result:any) => {
        extractedUrl= result;
        console.log(result); // logs "https://some.url.com" in the terminal
        cy.log("1:" + extractedUrl); // logs "1:https://some.url.com" in cypress UI
    });
    cy.log("2:"+ extractedUrl); // logs "2:" in cypress UI
    console.log(extractedUrl); // logs nothing
    cy.visit(extractedUrl);
});
```

I am probably missing something about how cypress handles async... I tried several different things :  `cy.wrap` and the `cypress-wait-until` plugin but couldn't find any way to make those work.

Actually I found one way which was to declare `extractedUrl` outside the test and begin a new test `it('...', () => {...})` : then, `extractedUrl` actually has the correct value at the beginning of the next test, but that is not ideal and I want to understand why.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please note that in cypress UI, I can see cypress is actually waiting for the task for a few seconds, then logs "2:". This is why I can't match my async knowledge to how this works in cypress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR; put your entire code inside the `then` callback

```js
it('should generate correct email', () => {
    const recipientEmail: string = 'some@email.com';
    const extractedUrl:string = '';

    // ....scenario generating a email to 'some@email.com'.....
    // plugin logs "https://some.url.com" after a few seconds
    cy.task('readMail', recipientEmail).then((result:any) => {
        extractedUrl= result;
        console.log(result); // logs "https://some.url.com" in the terminal
        cy.log("1:" + extractedUrl); // logs "1:https://some.url.com" in cypress UI
        cy.log("2:"+ extractedUrl); // logs "2:" in cypress UI
        console.log(extractedUrl); // logs nothing
        cy.visit(extractedUrl);
    });

});
```

Contrary to what it seems, Cypress commands do not return promises, they return promise-like object and the execution queue is handle by the Cypress framework. That's the main reason some actions that would be logical when handling promises will not work.

More info here: [Await-ing Cypress Chains #1417](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417#issuecomment-370860080)

You could also try [cypress-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise), that is a plugin to change cypress promise-like objects into actual promises. More info here: [Cypress.io — Using async and await by Nicholas Boll](https://medium.com/@NicholasBoll/cypress-io-using-async-and-await-4034e9bab207)

#### UPDATE #1:

You could also use alias in order to access the value:

```js
it('should generate correct email', () => {
    const recipientEmail: string = 'some@email.com';
    const extractedUrl:string = '';

    // ....scenario generating a email to 'some@email.com'.....
    // plugin logs "https://some.url.com" after a few seconds
    cy.task('readMail', recipientEmail).then((result:any) => {
        extractedUrl= result;
        cy.wrap(result).as('extractedUrl');
        console.log(result); // logs "https://some.url.com" in the terminal
        cy.log("1:" + extractedUrl); // logs "1:https://some.url.com" in cypress UI
    });

    cy.get('@extractedUrl').then((extractedUrl) => {
        cy.log("2:"+ extractedUrl); // logs "2:" in cypress UI
        console.log(extractedUrl); // logs nothing
        cy.visit(extractedUrl);
    })

});
```

Comment: So there is no way I can use await/async in cypress ? Anyway I tried the aliases approach and it seems to work ! Thanks !

Comment: No, is no really possible to use await/async inside tests code using cypress. You can use it in task and other plugins. Here is another good resource to understand why: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#How-Cypress-really-looks-Promises-wrapped-up-and-hidden-from-us

Comment: using wrap().as() in e.g. a beforeEach is updating the context and I can access the value via `this.<ALIAS>` – but why can't I use a wrap().as() inside the actual test and access it via context? why do I have to use the cy.get().then() construct?